# Should I put reject_rb_client on smtpd_client_restrictions or smtpd_recipient_restrictions?

Tags: postfix, email-server

I am configuring Postfix so that it can better defend itself against spam. The software has an option `reject_rbl_client [banlist]` that allows you to specify a URL banlist.

Should I be putting this option in `smtpd_client_restrictions` or `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`? What's the difference? In online examples, I see people putting it mainly in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`, but one tutorial places it in `smtpd_client_restrictions` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer on another Stack Overflow post. The difference between `smtpd_client_restrictions` and `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` is that the former is run earlier when a message is being processed. Normally, people put `reject_rbl_client` in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` because it is run later in message processing.

The benefit of running a DNS querying action later is so that we can put other less expensive checks in front (e.g. check for HELO validity) to weed out spam mail first, as spam banlists like Spamhaus will charge or flat out refuse to respond to servers who send it too many queries.